# Need Regex for HTML in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am facing a problem regarding HTML Regex.
My Problem is that I am working on a HTML part and i need only those tag which contains some inner text and i need regex for that and my HTML code is

```
<P id=a_bib3 class=Bib_entry unselectable="on">Demo Text</P>
<P id=a_bib3 class=Bib_entry unselectable="on">&nbsp;</P>
<P id=a_bib4 class=Bib_entry unselectable="on">&nbsp;</P>
<P id=a_bib5 class=Bib_entry unselectable="on">&nbsp;</P></code>
```

and now I need only first P tag which contains some inner Text.

Comment: Most probably you would be more satisfied if you pass this to e.g. jQuery and filter the appropriate elements out. Regexps are not meant for parsing HTML.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: You already have the entire DOM loaded and processed into a tree, why flatten it to do regex queries...

Comment: Even if you have the HTML as a string, you can easily parse it traverse the resulting DOM.

Comment: As others have said, parsing HTML with a regex is a bad idea.  You should pick a more suitable tool for the job.

Answer (score 1):

```
/<[pP](\s("[^"]*"|'[^']*'|[^"'>]+)*)?>[^<]*Demo Text[^<]*<\/[pP]\s*>/
```

Comment: Problem is, you cannot be sure this is actually a tag. For example it might be part of an attribute value: `<img title="<p>Demo Text</p>">`

Answer (score 0):

```
/<p\s+[^>]+>[^\&]+.*?<\/p>/mis
```

Comment: I downvoted because parsing html with regex is generally a bad idea, and it looks like this will fail if the inner text starts with `&` or if any inner attribute contains `>`

Comment: @murgatroid99: I confess I don't really know why one would operate on the HTML as a flat string when you already have it all parsed out into an ornate structure. However, one important reason to use regexes on HTML is when you are dealing with a fixed subset, such as in text editor when you want to do a search and replace on just one part, like just certain elements of one particular list or a table that you know holds no exceptional cases, nesting, comments, etc. Minimally people all need to know how to match `/<TAG\s+.*?>/mis` or `/<TAG\s+[^>]*>/i` plus `/<\/TAG>/i`, etc. But they seldom do.

Comment: @tchrist I can see that regexes would be useful in the case you describe, but my downvote still stands because GameBit's regex still discludes text starting with `&`.

Comment: @murgatroid99: He also has an escape on the ampersand, which is curious.

Comment: @tchrist I had just assumed that he was excluding text starting with `\`, but now that I look at a reference I am not even sure if that is a valid character class. I didn't mention it because I could not remember how backslashes are used in HTML.